# How to keep native spatial resolution while making a chart?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, chart

I have difficulties on producing chart in native spatial resolution. Please, look at the below script. The script allows to transform hourly GSMaP data into daily data and extract the values for given period as chart. But, to produce the chart I am required to specify the spatial scale which is "10000" in my script, while I would like to extract the data as chart in native resolution. If I delete the "10000" from chart line and run the script, GEE shows error: 
[image]
Please, help me to improve the script to be able to produce chart in native resolution.

```
var pts = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([65.945, 42.027]),
    aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[64.62748181270217, 43.19201550614239],
          [64.62748181270217, 40.77519027755922],
          [67.43998181270217, 40.77519027755922],
          [67.43998181270217, 43.19201550614239]]], null, false);

// Start and End Dates
var inidate = ee.Date('2014-02-01')
var enddate = ee.Date('2014-03-30')

//Import GSMaP data  
var img_1 = ee.ImageCollection("JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/reanalysis")
    .filterDate('2000-03-01', '2014-03-01').select('hourlyPrecipRateGC');

var img_2 = ee.ImageCollection("JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/operational")
    .filterDate('2014-03-01', '2030-12-31').select('hourlyPrecipRateGC');

var imgcol = img_1.merge(img_2)
    .filterDate(inidate, enddate); 

// Difference between start and end in days 
var difdate = enddate.difference(inidate, 'day')  

// Time lapse
var lapse = ee.List.sequence(0, difdate.subtract(1))
var listdates = lapse.map(function(day){
  return inidate.advance(day, 'day')
})

// Function for producing daily image collection
var daily_gsmap = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listdates.map(function(day){
  day = ee.Date(day);
  var daily_collection = imgcol.select('hourlyPrecipRateGC').filter(ee.Filter.date(day, day.advance(1, 'day')));
  return daily_collection.sum().clip(aoi).rename('daily_rainfall').set('date', day.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
        .set('system:time_start', day.millis()).set('system:time_end', day.millis());
}));

//Making chart and printing it
var chart_daily = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(daily_gsmap, pts, ee.Reducer.first(), 'daily_rainfall', 10000)
  .setChartType('ColumnChart');
  chart_daily.setOptions({
    title: 'Daily rainfall',
    vAxis: {title: 'Rainfall (mm)'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Date', format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'},
  });

print(chart_daily);
```

[image]

Comment: What is the native resolution that you're after? Have you tried replacing `10000` with that resolution?

Comment: @Kevin, native resolution of GSMaP image collection is 0.1 arc degrees. Is there any way to avoid specifying the 10000?

Comment: Hmm. It's weird that I can get away without specifying `scale` value. See [this script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8f17c67c6f61adbccd860c00d7855113)

Comment: @Kevin. But, if you make a function to convert hourly data to daily data and create new image collection, then it is not working.

Comment: @Kevin , I think I found why it is not working. I printed the .projection() of the image collection before the "hourly to daily data conversion" function and printed the .projection() after the function. There is a difference in "transform:", before it is [0.1,0,-180,0,-0.1,90], after [1,0,0,0,1,0]. I added screenshot of it to the question. How can I correct it?

Comment: Try adding `.reproject(imgcol.first().projection())` to the `return` line in your calculation of `daily_gsmap`. My best guess is the `sum` method results in a change in projection.

Comment: @Kevin, thank you. It is perfectly working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Kevin, the answer for the question is `reproject` images after `sum` in `return` line:

```
// Function for producing daily image collection
var daily_gsmap = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listdates.map(function(day)
    {
    day = ee.Date(day);
    var daily_collection = imgcol.select('hourlyPrecipRateGC')
        .filter(ee.Filter.date(day, day.advance(1, 'day')));
    return daily_collection.sum().clip(aoi).rename('daily_rainfall')
        .reproject(imgcol.first().projection())    
        .set('date', day.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
        .set('system:time_start', day.millis())
        .set('system:time_end', day.millis());
    }));
```